# grep directory names, filenames, and contents all at once?

Tags: grep

I'm writing a module for drupal. Its functionality is contingent on the directory name, certain file names, and function names being identical.

I'm troubleshooting now, and I wanted to to a search to see that I had an identical string in all the places I needed it to be, but I realized I would be missing the directory name and filename! Is there a way to do a grep or something that would search all that information?

For example, if my module was named `string`,  I would need

```
string/
string/string.module
  function string_function1() {...}
  function string_function2() {...}
```

If I did my `everythinggrep string .` and I saw

```
string/
  function string_function1() {...}
  function string_function2() {...}
```

I would know that I had misnamed my module file.

Comment: Would the file actually be string.module?

Comment: @k.parnell Yes. The directory name, the first part of the file name, and the first parts of function names must all be identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in a single statement, but in two statements:

For searching in text-files:

```
grep -RI "string" directory/*
```

For finding file-names:

```
find directory -type f -name "*string*" -ls
```